# Why is the aspect ratio for this UV-unwrap wrong?

Tags: uv

I have been at this for days now, but I can't figure it out.
Why is the point / pinacle in the uv-unwrap not centered like it is in the object?

[image]

[image]
[blender object and the uv](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X1tJO.jpg)

Comment: No images visible, did you use imgur?

Answer (score 1):

Like i said i'm still a novice.

The devil was in the details, as a result of the beveling on the top there were still some minor issues (overlapping face, 2 vertices to be joined) at the outer right side of the object. After I took care of those issues the unwrap already looked much better.
Because the front face still showed some stretching, I divided (1 time horizontal and vertical) the front face. Then the unwrap worked like a charm with almost no stretching / deformation.

Took me many days, but i learned a lot !!